# Any Jquery/AJAX etc. tool have Chrome like SpellChecker With Multiple Language Support

Tags: java, spell-checking, zk

I will want to add Google chrome kind Spell checker in my web application which will work in all major browser mainly in IE , Anyone used any third party tool in Jquery which can integrated in Java web application easily. Also i have to give option to user add words in dictionary.Please let me know if someone used such kid of SpellChecker.

```
Note:-I do not want Server Hit for Spell Checking only when user select add to dictionary at that time i will want to save that into some DB table
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try visiting any of these links and try out the demos.

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/10/free-jquery-spell-checker-plugins.html.html

http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/

Comment: Thanks i already checked these link but they are not giving the option of add the word into dictionary as given by Chrome

Comment: You can try this link for a couple of other spell checkers that support dictionaries: http://freebiesdesign.com/4-best-jquery-spell-checker-plugins/#.UcKvWhV91pg

Comment: Sorry not fulfill my requirements :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plugin we used for our project and works like a charm:

https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Thanks Manish . Can it support Multiple Language and we can add words in dictionary like Google chrome provides? Also Download link have no any package.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes it does support multiple languages and do support ignoreforever or add-to-dictionary. You can download distribution zip from https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker/archive/master.zip

Comment: Did you impleted it in your Java Web Project any exaplme how we can implement it